# Working with Large PolygonsDataFrame in R - Adding Time Variable

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, spatial, rgdal

I am a newbie here and especially in the analysis of spatial data. I am currently working on my PhD with the topic "Spatial Analysis of Mental Health" and I am stuck at one point.

I am working with representative surveys, I can add the survey values to a polygon data frame and plot them as well. Now I have a question and unfortunately I don't know what to do and hope you can help me.

This is my Polygon Data Frame:

```
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 431 
extent      : 3280359, 3921536, 5237511, 6103443  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7 +units=m +no_defs 
variables   : 23
names       : ADE, GF, BSG,    RS,   AGS,       SDV_RS,       GEN,        BEZ, IBZ,           BEM,  NBD, SN_L, SN_R, SN_K, SN_V1, ... 
min values  :   4,  2,   1, 01001, 01001, 010010000000, Ahrweiler,      Kreis,  40,            --,   ja,   01,    0,   00,    00, ... 
max values  :   4,  4,   1, 16077, 16077, 160770001001,   Zwickau, Stadtkreis,  46, Sonderverband, nein,   16,    9,   91,    00, ...
```

`EDIT MY QUESTION FROM THIS POINT`

I have a data frame with following Information:

```
> df
# A tibble: 99,014 x 6
   date                  KRS WMW10 WMW25 NewInfect DeprIndex
   <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 2020-03-14 00:00:00  1001    NA    NA         4     -4.08
 2 2020-03-18 00:00:00  1001    NA    NA         2     -4.08
 3 2020-03-19 00:00:00  1001    NA    NA         4     -4.08
 4 2020-03-20 00:00:00  1001    NA    NA         2     -4.08
 5 2020-03-21 00:00:00  1001    NA    NA         1     -4.08
 6 2020-03-24 00:00:00  1001    NA    NA         1     -4.08
 7 2020-03-26 00:00:00  1001    NA    NA         4     -4.08
 8 2020-03-27 00:00:00  1001    NA    NA         1     -4.08
 9 2020-03-28 00:00:00  1001    NA    NA         2     -4.08
10 2020-03-29 00:00:00  1001    NA    NA         1     -4.08
# ... with 99,004 more rows
```

I have dates beginning from 2020-01-01 until 2020-11-25 in daily steps. The Variable KRS is the county code. The other variables are measures.

In another step I gathered the df:

```
df2<-df%>%
  select(date,KRS,WMW10,WMW25,NewInfect,DeprIndex) %>%
  gather(key = "variable", value="value", -date,-KRS)
```

So I got new df like this:

```
 A tibble: 396,056 x 4
   date                  KRS variable value
   <dttm>              <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
 1 2020-03-14 00:00:00  1001 WMW10       NA
 2 2020-03-18 00:00:00  1001 WMW10       NA
 3 2020-03-19 00:00:00  1001 WMW10       NA
 4 2020-03-20 00:00:00  1001 WMW10       NA
 5 2020-03-21 00:00:00  1001 WMW10       NA
 6 2020-03-24 00:00:00  1001 WMW10       NA
 7 2020-03-26 00:00:00  1001 WMW10       NA
 8 2020-03-27 00:00:00  1001 WMW10       NA
 9 2020-03-28 00:00:00  1001 WMW10       NA
10 2020-03-29 00:00:00  1001 WMW10       NA
# ... with 396,046 more row
```

I think I have now my df2 in a long format. But as in my first question I want to analyse the data in weekly way. So I build up a new Variable week in this way:

```
df2$week<-strftime(df2$date, format = "%V")
```

This worked so far really good and smooth. I have now 48 weeks (ISO 8601).

At this point I have problems. I wanted to make an space time dataframe with the package **spacetime**. And used a Tutorial as orientation (https://edzer.github.io/UseR2016/).

So I am using the polygon data frame mentioned in the beginning of my thread. In the tutorial they are creating with the package *map* a map, but I can't create with *map* a German map on county level, so I downloaded a shapefile. So far no problems, I thought....

My Code:

```
weeks<- 01:48
time<-as.POSIXct(paste(weeks, sep = ""), tz="GMT")

Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

My next Steps would be, as far as I understood the tutorial:

```
library(spacetime)
df_st<-STFDF(map,time,df3)

#I know, I should use the command **STSDF** because of the missing values,
but with **STSDF** I have the problem with _index_, _time_ and _endTime_

STSDF(sp = map,time = time ,data = df3 ,index = ? ,endTime = ?)
```

So I am stucking at this point. My questions are how can I create a spacetimeDF, with the data I have?

I hope someone can really help me.

Kind regards
Ari

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `merge` method

```
map2 <- merge( map, NewInfect, by.x="AGS", by.y="KRS")
```

It is very risky to do it in other ways, and you should never directly write to the @data slot, because this may mess up the relation between the geometries and the attributes.

As you have many observations for the same geometry, you also need to use the argument `duplicateGeoms=TRUE`

```
map2 <- merge( map, NewInfect, by.x="AGS", by.y="KRS", duplicateGeoms=TRUE)
```

That would lead to a lot of duplication of the polygon geometries. You can also make them for one week at a time, as needed, by subsetting `NewInfect`. Or you can look into space-time objects (but it may not be easier to use these at first)

Comment: I am really glad, that you answered. I was hoping you will answer on my question. Thanks a lot!
I did it as you said and it seems like it worked - Thanks for that again.
From this point I don't exactly know what to do. My main Question is: How can I analyze the data for example making a regression model?
Do you have any hints and help for me? like an really good tutorial?

Comment: is it possible to contact you? I really stuck at one point and I know if I get a hint for a solution I will do it. I hope I can contact you. 
Best regards
Ari

Comment: sorry, I cannot offer general help like that